# Conditionally activate "acts_on_list" when field is defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I have a model "entry" and I need it to act like a list when a `playlist_id` is specified, but if it's not, I need it to not act like a list. (acts_as_list is a gem I'm using)

In my model code I have:

```
acts_as_list scope: :playlist
```

I need to figure out the best way to do this. I'm thinking of subclassing a model maybe, but I'd prefer to just keep it as one model but add this additional logic. I don't know the order of initialization for `active_record` so I'm not sure where I could mess with things like this and where I can't.

(The reason why I need to do this: I want to have loose items that belong to another model, simply sorted by date. As my "default list" has grown in size, I'm experiencing some performance issues since we have to look up the last entry in a list to know the position of the newest item.)

Comment: What does it mean "when its inside a playlist" ?

Comment: Updated question. Essentially I meant when a `playlist_id` is specified.

Answer (score 0):

My shallow understanding is the model projection may need improvement. In my understanding `act_as_list` is better for `has_many` - `belongs_to` relationship, say a todo is exactly in a Todo list.

But in your case, let's say the entry is a song. A playlist can have many songs and a song can belongs to many playlist. So the relationship is many to many.

I think you need an intermediate model say `ListItem` to represent such relationship

```
class PlayList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :entries, through: :list_items
end

class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :play_list
  belongs_to :entires
  acts_as_list scope: :play_list
end

class Entries < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :play_lists, through: :list_items
```

By this design, what you sort on PlayList is only the list items, not the entries. Performance should be improved a lot as longs as on playlist doesn't contain too much list_items, which should be common.

Comment: We have many list items, hence the issue. This might be useful for others, but not for our circumstance.

Comment: I am afraid you read too quickly. You have lots of entries, but you don't have list_items yet, according to the question.